# How to find the string length in a field?

Tags: mysql

I believe there is a function that I can use to determine the string length but I can't find it on Google. What I want is all rows greater than 255 characters. Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from table
where length(somefield) > 255;
```

You have the strange wording that "some row is greater than 255 characters".  That might mean

```
select *
from table
where length(somefield1) + length(somefield2) + length(somefield3) > 255;
```

Comment: "you have the strange wording" ... earned my day.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `length()`*****, and `char_length()`. See [http://dev.mysql.com/doc...function_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) and [http://dev.mysql.com/doc...function_char-length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

**Example:**

```
SELECT  name, email
  FROM  subscribers
  WHERE (char_length(name) > 5)
  LIMIT 1
```

--

<sup>* Returns the length of the string str, measured in bytes. A multi-byte character counts as multiple bytes. This means that for a string containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that but I'm not quite sure how to use that with a where clause and I can't find an example

Answer (score 0):

You can not find the length of a row (unless that row is made up of only one field).  You can find the length of individual fields in a row which have string data in them with `length()` and `char_length()`.